# Why Speed and duplex Unknown?

Tags: networking, 16.04

I'm adding a Network card (OneConnect 10Gb) on Ubuntu 16.04 and run the `ethtool` command but output shows `speed and duplex  unknown!.`

Any idea how to fix this problem?

```
xxx:~# ethtool  enp12s0f0
Settings for enp12s0f0:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full
                                10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised link modes:  Not reported
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        **Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)**
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: external
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00002000 (8192)
                               hw
        Link detected: no
```

**Ethernet device driver and firmware information:**

```
driver: be2net
version: 10.6.0.3
firmware-version: 4.0.360.3
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:0c:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

**Detailed vendor information**

```
*-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: OneConnect 10Gb NIC
       vendor: Emulex Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: enp12s0f0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:00:c9:c2:99:94
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre 1000bt-fd
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=be2net driverversion=10.6.0.3 firmware=4.0.360.3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=fibre
       resources: irq:16 memory:fc57c000-fc57ffff memory:fc540000-fc55ffff memory:fc520000-fc53ffff memory:fc300000-fc37ffff
```

**Ethernet card(s) available on your system**

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5708 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 12)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5708 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 12)
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Emulex Corporation OneConnect 10Gb NIC (rev 02)
0c:00.1 Ethernet controller: Emulex Corporation OneConnect 10Gb NIC (rev 02)
```

Thank You ..

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Since the card supports options about the wire connection that are negotiated with the Other End, the card can't know these values pre-connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface is fiber with only one supported speed `1000baseT/Full`,
`Auto-negotiation: off` and without media connected or detected:  `Link detected: no`
But you mentioned the network card is 10Gb. There is no way that card is able connect to 10Gbps node at opposite side if setting is as you wrote.

If you wish to use 1Gbps, check the fibre cable, media type (multimode/singlemode) and wave length on both ends (SM: 850 / 1300 / 1310 nm or MM: 1550 nm).